# JS/TS Accessing method from class returns undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

In Typescript / Javascript, given the class:

```
class T {
    method_a() {
        console.log('Inside method a');
    }
}
```

I need to access the (unbounded) method like this, but it gots `undefined` instead:

```
const method_to_be_passed = T.method_a; // undefined
```

In python, I would get the unbound method like this:

```py
class P:
    def method_a():
        print('inside method a')

the_method = P.method_a  # <function P.method_a at 0x7fee48eff310>
```

And then I can bound it to an object to call it. How would I do the equivalent in TS / JS?

The typescript compiler says the following error:

`error TS2339: Property 'method_a' does not exist on type 'typeof T'.`

Comment: Or make method_a static or execute your code on an instance of T object:  t = new T()

Comment: Why do you say "unbounded"? `method_a` is an **instance (prototype) method** not a "static method".  To get a reference to it use `const fn = T.prototype.method_a`

Comment: JS and Py are dynamic typing languages but they have totally different paradigms. What is that actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that a `class` definition in JavaScript/TypeScript is just syntactic sugar (i.e. *just shorthand*) for defining a constructor-function and `prototype` properties:

So this

```
class T {

    val: number = 1;

    method_a() {
        console.log('Inside method a');
    }
}
```

<sub>(I added the `val` property as an additional example)</sub>

Is equivalent to this:

```
function T() {
    this.val = 1;
}

T.prototype.method_a = function() {
    console.log('Inside method a');
};
```

Therefore, to get a reference to the `method_a` function you need to use the `prototype` qualifier:

```
const method_to_be_passed = T.prototype.method_a;
```

This is different to other languages like Python, C#, C++, etc that let you reference both instance and non-instance (i.e. `static`) of a type without additional qualification (of course you cannot meaningfully use instance members without a `this` parameter, of course).

---

If you want `method_a` to *not* require a `this` parameter then you need to make it a static member:

```
class T {

    val: number = 1;

    static method_a() {
        console.log('Inside method a');
    }
}
```

which *does* allow you to do this:

```
const method_to_be_passed = T.method_a;
```

---

Playground example:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEASkEkB2EAuYnAKYFksFsAjLAJxgG8AoS6W6ANzBAC5okBXI06AXmgEYA3NTrQA5llQMmABRDsI-ABQBKVhy4loVUaJKT2JJNFQALAJYQAdIxDQA1AOGiAviLrmU6TFgBi7TFVtGl1aYAB7FHCQLCsQcLElAHJPNAxsf0wklWc6NzdKUEgYeAgAZXRUc2A8TQgqENo0quBpFjZOYi0+IXcmyurxSTa5BWU1Ds1g0Np9VENjUoqwFtqu61sHJ0boAtFmwYPgTOAgnRmIqJi4hOSjk+zc2nygA

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, instance methods of a class can be accessed via the class's `prototype`:

```js
class T {
    method_a() {
        console.log('Inside method a');
    }
}

const method_to_be_passed = T.prototype.method_a;
```

Note that if you reference the `this` instance of your class inside your method, you will need to bind your method to some instance of class `T` like so:

```js
const method_to_be_passed = T.prototype.method_a.bind(some_instance_of_T);
```

Comment: was close to downvote you answer (as it was ~ to Dai's post) and than I saw 'bind' so will upvote it

Comment: @DraganS \*grumble\*